# web push UnauthorizedRegistration error 400

Tags: javascript, c#, git, web, push-notification

I am using web push, and have followed the [this codelab](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/) to learn how to register users.

For the back end I am going to use this library to send the push messages: 
https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push-csharp

I noticed that some users in Chrome have one of two possible origins when I register them:

Either `fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send` or `android.googleapis.com/gcm/send`.

I've added all the parameters to the back end library and I'm trying to bulk send notifications to all users.

When I send messages I use `vapidDetails` for all messages and I saw that only the users with ID that start with `fcm.googleapis.com` the push message would send correctly. For all the users with `android.googleapis.com`, I got the error `UnauthorizedRegistration`. So I tried to use `gcmAPIKey`.

I got the key from Firebase, I saw that was 2 key so i try them, I read also that in the web site that the user is register I need to put file name manifest.json with the `gcm_sender_id` so i did it ...

all the code that i am using if from the two library from the top .

i give example for what i send and the response that i get from fcm that work and from gcm that didnt work .
i am also try to read this problem but nothing solve my problem

```
{
  Method: POST,
  RequestUri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send/f9PkPIROxKo:APA91bESvQBjMpHDmi_InXNHScEFt_-xWy4zEYhUfQvS6W78YBVZLrDGoYnKkw21bYjbTU0Q6zk_VXt8qdEiQtNEe0W2znE2Ho4_gYh5yLhqPZt8CHFrhhmUWdZaWpIlFDwvS8FhOALA', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent,
  Headers: {
    TTL: 2419200
    Encryption: salt=mfZ6vUxS7u3Xo5jDPau_NA
    Authorization: key=AAAAZYYARKI:APA91bEIdVZ3LiZUsL0CgWmQTkz6hK_U8OPMTjuMt_6Ux2PmNNGGZEluzllixLIQHEDjUYygENPN8MCmnTmhxnPD29WfyHJrDVZjEUzbl7u--1NQVI49pYtag9kijSBsDw-mE4b6lOvD
    Crypto-Key: dh=BIBz0FvQPs6BdNCwFut_vHwU-Tk-pyuCBxnxqOSufo4EHEaps0DZ5lZjSTG46RcI53D-Dkj6uMHqyw9X5r2u_Hk
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 74
    Content-Encoding: aesgcm
  }
}

{
  StatusCode: 400,
  ReasonPhrase: 'UnauthorizedRegistration', 
  Version: 1.1, 
  Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 
  Headers: {
      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
      Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
      Vary: Accept-Encoding
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      Accept-Ranges: none
      Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
      Date: Thu, 18 May 2017 07:28:48 GMT
      Server: GSE
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
      Expires: Thu, 18 May 2017 07:28:48 GMT
  }
}
```

and for the fcm that work :

```
{
  Method: POST,
  RequestUri: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/e1N5dtHsikc:APA91bEHZztef21cjooCnaPu_lAmcYjA2twELeecS7wIuJibbpptAlUdYaVHNkVukph5qy9mnVml3qenqti1Yz7wUqL6A-UY3h-Ifkv1dnxSsngPIvmG8VXMmjy66aSvJ1DtI1p3W3Sm', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent,
  Headers: {
      TTL: 2419200
      Encryption: salt=W1Y-iRlHUu1spMta3etHGw
      Authorization: WebPush eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2ZjbS5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQ5NTEzNTQ2OCwic3ViIjoibWFpbHRvOm9maXJAZmllbGRzb2ZsZWFkcy5jb20ifQ.zZ5cqwhbGNHDhO_swjwdxjqnCczFrOFoAJSvjMP2Xeylt5C6MfGwNz92vZWMPkiJwhHrJZt9nmsbrh_6ghxaLw
      Crypto-Key: dh=BLeaQC8dvMuxASHFsp4_8kcExsa6yZcT1V2x7MZJnUGgSxq3JXYa6JN7Rm6xtPpwA0Q5tftSdy6dR7P1ZMztPMs;p256ecdsa=BDd3_hVL9fZi9Ybo2UUzA284WG5FZR30_95YeZJsiApwXKpNcF1rRPF3foIiBHXRdJI2Qhumhf6_LFTeZaNndIo
      Content-Type: application/json
      Content-Length: 74
      Content-Encoding: aesgcm
  }
}

{
  StatusCode: 201,
  ReasonPhrase: 'Created',
  Version: 1.1,
  Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent,
  Headers: {
      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
      Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
      Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
      Date: Thu, 18 May 2017 07:25:38 GMT
      Location: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/0:1495092338974351%0f493ae6f9fd7ecd
      Server: GSE
      Content-Length: 0
      Content-Type: text/plain
      Expires: Thu, 18 May 2017 07:25:38 GMT
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's break this problem down into 2:

### 1. Why are there two different origins?

In newer versions of Chrome (and Samsung Internet Browser) you can pass in an `applicationServerKey` and this will return the `fcm.googleapis.com` push subscriptions.

If you don't supply an `applicationServerKey` OR you're in a browser that doesn't support the `applicationServerKey` but *does* support the proprietary `gcm_sender_id` parameter in the web app manifest, then you'll be given the `android.googleapis.com` endpoint.

### 2. Why can't you make it work?

My hunch is that you've mashed together the codelab you originally linked to and [my simple push demo](https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo/issues/169).

Since you said you made a Firebase project **after** you already had `android.googleapis.com` subscription, I'm 99% certain that you used someone else's `gcm_sender_id` meaning that only the owner of that project can send messages to that user. If you delete those users from your database, register again with your own `gcm_sender_id`, if should work.

Info on gcm_sender_id and details on what to do to get it working with Firebase: https://web-push-book.gauntface.com/chapter-06/01-non-standards-browsers/

Answer (score 0):

- One of situations you will meet this error described following:

  [One will produce the wrong process](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=638924&can=2&q=638924&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)

  And Google tutorial also mention following:

  `open DevTools (Right Click > Inspect) and go to the Application panel, click the Service Workers tab and check the Update on Reload checkbox. When this checkbox is enabled the service worker is forcibly updated every time the page reloads.`
- If you want to push notification with payload in website:

  Add `applicationServerKey` in when you `subscribe`
- If you add `applicationServerKey` in when `subscribe`

  1. Keys generated by openssl not work for me.
  2. Keys generated by vapid not work for me.
  3. **Keys generated by website mentioned in google tutorial works.**
- Workable keys generator(include public server application key and private key):
  [Workable keys generator](https://web-push-codelab.appspot.com/)
- Workable google tutorial:
  [Workable google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/)

**Conclution**

1. I add `applicationServerKey` and cause errors
2. I use `Workable keys generator` but still errors
3. I follow `Google tutorial` to update service worker to prevent some error
4. works